# Conditional Rendering for more for more then one condition in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set *additional* Conditional Rendering for two components that currently already have a condition set:

```
{!this.state.isEdit &&
   <Todo
     onCompleted={this.handleCompleted}
     todos={this.state.todos}
     onEdit={this.handleEdit}
     onDelete={this.handleDelete}

   />
   }

   {this.state.isEdit &&
    <Useredit
      onCompleted={this.handleCompleted}
      onEdit={this.handleEdit}
      value={this.state.editText} 
      onChange={this.handleEditChange} 
      onChangeSelect={this.handleSelectChange}
      todos={this.state.todos}
      onDelete={this.handleDelete}
      onSave={this.handleSave}

      /> 
    }
```

How can I add another condition to these two components for a different and unrelated condition while preserving the original condition I have set? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
{!this.state.isEdit && (someSecondCondition) &&
  <Todo
    onCompleted={this.handleCompleted}
    todos={this.state.todos}
    onEdit={this.handleEdit}
    onDelete={this.handleDelete}
  />
}

{this.state.isEdit && (someWeirdCondition || someOtherWeirdCondition) &&
  <Useredit
    onCompleted={this.handleCompleted}
    onEdit={this.handleEdit}
    value={this.state.editText} 
    onChange={this.handleEditChange} 
    onChangeSelect={this.handleSelectChange}
    todos={this.state.todos}
    onDelete={this.handleDelete}
    onSave={this.handleSave}
  /> 
}
```

Just replace `someSecondCondition` and so on to suit your case. For more information you should learn about how `&&` and `||` operator works and in the case of true and false, which section of the code will be rendered.

Better yet, to improve scalability/readability/maintainability, remove your logic into another method.

```
handleViews = () => {
  if(!this.state.isEdit) {
    return (
      <Todo
        onCompleted={this.handleCompleted}
        todos={this.state.todos}
        onEdit={this.handleEdit}
        onDelete={this.handleDelete}
      />
    )
  } else if(this.state.isEdit) {
    return (
      <Useredit
        onCompleted={this.handleCompleted}
        onEdit={this.handleEdit}
        value={this.state.editText} 
        onChange={this.handleEditChange} 
        onChangeSelect={this.handleSelectChange}
        todos={this.state.todos}
        onDelete={this.handleDelete}
        onSave={this.handleSave}

      /> 
    );
  }
}


render() {
  return <View>{this.handleViews()}</View>
}
```